AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'get_user_token'
Following along here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=3
At step 4, I've built and run the app, entered 1 but then get:
main.py", line 56, in display_access_token
    token = await graph.get_user_token()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'get_user_token'

As mentioned in the link above, the code for the Graph class is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=3
Any suggestions as to how I can solve this?

What did you name your class? I think it should be named Graph.

@Rukmini see link to full code.

The error "AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'get_user_token" suggests that the method get_user_token is not recognized within the Graph class.

Make sure you class is named as Graph.
Make sure that the get_user_token method is defined correctly within the Graph class and is not commented out or missing.

I used the below code and worked successfully:
import asyncio
from azure.identity import DeviceCodeCredential
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, client_id: str, tenant_id: str, graph_scopes: list):
        self.device_code_credential = DeviceCodeCredential(client_id, tenant_id=tenant_id)
        self.graph_scopes = graph_scopes  
        self.user_client = GraphServiceClient(self.device_code_credential, graph_scopes)

    async def get_user_token(self):
        access_token = self.device_code_credential.get_token(' '.join(self.graph_scopes))  
        return access_token.token

async def display_access_token(graph: Graph):
    token = await graph.get_user_token()
    print('User token:', token, '\n')

async def main():
    client_id = "ClientID"
    tenant_id = "TenantID"
    graph_scopes = ["User.Read", "Mail.Read"] 

    graph = Graph(client_id, tenant_id, graph_scopes)
    await display_access_token(graph)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())



